# Properly printing a 2D array?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

Currently working on writing a Conways life in C# for class. I've been taking small steps to get a hang out the language and game programming in general and have hit a snag in printing my 2D char array. Currently I'm using GetLength - 1 to not go over the bound but it fails to print out the last chars in the array.

What my initial file looks like

```
 +*++
 ++*+
 ****
```

After its read into placed into Char (i believe)

```
 *  
  * 
****
```

What ends up printed

```
  *

**



using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConwaysLife
{
    class Program
    {
        static char[,] universe;
        static void bigBang(int h, int w, List<string> grid)
        {
            universe = new char[h,w];

            int row = 0;

            foreach (string line in grid)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (line.ToCharArray()[i] == '*')
                    {
                        universe[row, i] = '*';
                    }
                }
                row++;
            }
        }

         //How I'm attempting to print out my 2D char array
        static void offspring()
        {
            StringBuilder cellLine = new StringBuilder();
            for (int y = 0; y < universe.GetLength(1)-1; y++)
             {
                for (int x = 0; x < universe.GetLength(0)-1; x++)
                {
                    Console.Write(universe[y, x]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();                
            }
            //pause
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> tempLine = new List<string>();

            //Console.WriteLine("File Path?");
            int width = 0;
            int height = 0;

            //read file into List
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("life.txt"))
            {
                while (r.Peek() >= 0)
                {
                    tempLine.Add(r.ReadLine());

                    //compare current width to new width
                    if (tempLine[height].Length >= width) { width = tempLine[height].Length; }

                    //increase height when going to next row
                    height++;
                }
                bigBang(height, width, tempLine);
            }
            offspring();
        }
    }
}
```

Update Offspring()

```
static void offspring()
        {
            StringBuilder cellLine = new StringBuilder();
            for (int x = 0; x <= universe.GetLength(1); x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y <= universe.GetLength(0); y++)
                {
                    Console.Write(universe[x, y]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            //pause
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Nothing to do with your real problem, but strings in c# have an indexer, so there's no need to use "ToCharArray", you can just do line[i]

Comment: Thanks. I was probably just writing it up and thought I had found a shortcut :p Guess not!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'll delve deeper as to why it wasn't working as I expected it to I simply passed the sizes of the array when I created it to my offspring() and used those values when printing. Once that small change was the done the output came out as expected.

```
 *  
  * 
****
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an off-by-one error in your `offspring` function. Note that you're doing it correctly in the `bigBang` function.

You are looping while `x < GetLength()-1`. You just need `x < GetLength()`, because that excludes the case when `x == GetLength()`.

An analagous loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
   Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Output:

> 0
>   1
>   2
>   3

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the game principles, but there's a problem in your `offspring` method.

```
y < universe.GetLength(1)-1
```

This translates to `y < 3 - 1` or `y < 2`, making your iteration go from y = 0 to 1.

To fix, simply remove the two occurences of `-1`.

```
        for (int y = 0; y < universe.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < universe.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
```

In addition, you have your indices reversed when you access `universe`.

```
Console.Write(universe[y, x]);
```

There you're using the y variable to access the row, and x for the column. The inverse should be done like this:

```
Console.Write(universe[x, y]);
```

Giving a final output of

```
++*
*+*
+**
++*
```

Comment: Your suggestion work but the print out appears up-side down. I've updated the top with my updated offspring() but it still fall out of index when printed right side up.

Comment: Can you provide the expected output? I see you switched the order of your two for loops, which should print the same structure as your input.